# Data Extension Clone

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was trying to copy the data extension but unable to find a way. 
Is there any way to clone the data extension, including the data inside that extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Answer: No. Or it depends what you regards as simple.

1. Copy the source dataextension (lets say it is named X)
2. Name the copied dataextension Y
3. Now write a SQL Query that looks like: `SELECT (all fields seperated by comma) FROM [X]`

> You can search for the source dataextension when you are about to
>   create the sql and drag it into the query canvas and it will create
>   all the fields that are inside the source DE

4. Make the target of that query dataextension Y
5. Run the query

I believe this question has already been asked. In future please research more on this plattform and read the guides on [how to ask a question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey @Johannes
Thank you very much for this.

Comment: Hey @johannes 
I created a new attribute in the data extension and I want to update that attribute with some value, is it possible with SQL or I need to update that with manually process?

Comment: "that attribute with some value" is a little bit to generic. I need more information. Is this value stored somewhere else? Can you query it in an sql statement? Is it static? Do you only need to set one row or do you update thousands/millions? Do you have a primary key in your dataextension? Please add more information so i can understand your use case better

Comment: Yes, I have a primary key in my DE and it is a million records, No value is not stored anywhere and yes it is a static value.

Comment: `select 'staticvalue' as TargetDataExtensionColumnName` is your query to your target de. or you can edit your existing one and add another field in the select it will be `,'staticvalue' as TargetDataExtensionColumnName`. Target is Y

Comment: Hello @Johannes 
Thanks you very much for this details.

Answer (score 0):

One more technique [simple 2 steps]

1) Duplicate the DE. [using Contact Builder]

2) Open the duplicated DE --> Records --> Import Into Data Extension

Follow as in below below screenshots. TADAAA! simple.

[image]

[image]